# CRM 2011 - Adding Data Via a Solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing CRM 2011 solutions for a company, which is all great except for adding data.

Basically I'm creating 2 new Entities (as well as other things) which are SpecialisationType and Specialisation.

The Specialisations Types would be: Languages, Operating Systems, etc....

Then specialisations would be: C# (type = Languages), Windows 7 (type = Operating Systems)

You get the idea.

Now I can create a solution with these entities fine, but how do I get it to also import the data?  I know I could do that afterwards using import but that's not nice.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

No, solutions cannot include default data. You'll have to create those after import of the solution. Personally, this is one of my top requests for improving solutions in the future.

Comment: Is there no way to get around this like creating a process/plugin that runs once at install to add the data?

Comment: You can certainly include a workflow or plugin of some sort to handle that process... that's something that we've done before. However, it will still require something to kick it off... creation of a record, manually starting a workflow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Configuration Page for your solution might make it easier for the user to import these special one-time records. You could build a bit of JavaScript that would create these special records, and then include instructions for the user to click a button on the Configuration Page of the Solution. Here's a link about the special Configuration Page:

http://mahenderpal.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/step-by-step-adding-configuration-page-in-solution-ms-crm-2011/